# Multicast for Tomcat servers on Google Cloud

Tags: networking, tomcat, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, multicast

Google Cloud VPC networks only support IPv4 unicast traffic [1], they do not support broadcast, multicast or IPv6 traffic within the network.  I have several tomcat servers and I'd like to group them into a cluster, but without multicast it seems I can't.

Is there any way to make this Tomcat cluster working in the Google Cloud VPC?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use overlay network deployment to have mcast/bcast support inside. 
"Third-party partner solutions such as Weave Net, Cohesive Networks, or Ravello can help you enable these features by using their overlay network solutions. Or you can build your own overlay network by using open technologies such as VXLAN."
REF: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/delivering-aggregated-travel-data-with-minimal-latency

Answer (score 2):

I think it’s better to use static cluster.

There are 2 types of cluster:

Static Tomcat Cluster

Dynamic Tomcat Cluster

In static cluster there is not need multicast, because each tomcat we statically defined/configured the other instances. But dynamic Cluster we are not defined anything. so each tomcat in that cluster some how to identify the other tomcat instances.

You can find more details here: https://www.ramkitech.com/2012/11/tomcat-clustering-series-part-3-session.html